# How to add an entry to Gnome's context Menu?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

how can I add an item to Gnome's context menu?
I want 'shred' to be in there, too.
KR

Comment: You want to add an item to the context menu in *Nautilus* that appears when you right click a file or folder?

Comment: Voting to move this Q to superuser.com

Comment: Ok, can I myself move this question to superueser or does only a mod have the required privileges?

Comment: With the keyword 'Nautilus', I just found the solution.

Comment: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=246539

Answer (score 8):

Install nautilus-actions:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Now you can define new action in: `System > Preferences > Nautilus Actions Configuration`

In the Action tab fill:

- Context label = `shred`

In the Command tab fill:

- Path = `/usr/bin/shred`
- Parameters = `-f -u -z %M`

You may need to restart Nautilus, run:

```
nautilus -q
```